# GIT: Ignore file when pulling but not when pushing

Tags: git, git-pull

I have a GIT repo to do frontend mostly: Scss preprocessor and JS.

The problem is that we change different .scss files and compile them into a .css one (we are 4, 5 and sometimes 6 frontends) and it gives a conflict when pulling. .css files always throw a conflict.

This is reasonable, since .css file is always different, but I want to ignore those conflicts, since we have a LOT of merges to solve those conflicts (Unnecessary merges, from our point of view) .

I cannot ignore the .css file in GIT, because project managers and others are always pulling the repo to test and show to clients.

Is there a way that we can always PUSH our .CSS file but not PULL it?

Comment: Not sure what your problem really is, but it sounds to me like you're simply not using the awsome power of branches enough (1 branch per front-end would be the _bare_ minimum, if you want to work on those branches, then 2 branches per front-end would be the minimum of branches to use)

Answer (score 3):

The canonical answer is that you're doing it wrong and you're *not* supposed to store generated files, such as these `.css` in your case. Typical workflow and environment to work with generated (compiled) files usually involves:

- Storing only sources in version control
- Developers each compile their own target files (usually slightly different due to environment differences) using their own development boxes / environments
- There is some sort of "deployment" process that compiles and produces "deployable artifacts" (i.e. in *stable* environment with *reproducible* results, given the same set of source files)
- These artifacts have the following life cycle:artifacts:

  - first, they get deployed to the stage environment,
  - then QA checks it throughly,
  - finally they get deployed into production.

However, your mileage may vary, of course. Could you elaborate, what was your original reason to commit generated files into the repository?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I add generated files because "managers" are using the files in the repository:  the "pull" files and show HTML design to clients.  I suposse that ?ll have to use GRUNT to make a correct deploy.

Comment: "Managers" generally shouldn't have to use repository directly, or, if they do, they have to run some sort of build process to get the result. Alternatively, you might want to demonstrate results to clients in some pre-set environment (ideally, always running and ready to be showcased) - that's exactly what "stage" environment usually is for.